# Known Redundant Flag is not Identified in Flag Dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed

Earlier this morning, I flagged an answer as VLQ because instead of answering the question, the user posted contact info and request that the OP contact him privately. There was no useful content in the answer at all.

The flag is shown in my flag history and is still listed as "active". However, if I click on "flag" on the answer again, I still see the normal flag box and can select VLQ flag again, instead of the usual red text that says I have already raised that type of flag.

Is there a reason that an active VLQ flag may not cause the flag dialog box to tell me that I have already raised one?

### Flag History of VLQ Flag:

[image]

### Flag Dialog with Active VLQ flag:

[image]

Conversely, if I visit a question with an active "Too Broad" flag, I get the expected red warnings.

### Flag Dialog with Active Too Broad flag:

[image]

Both flags are active, so they have not been handled. What accounts for one active flag resulting in a restricted flag dialog, but not the other?

Comment: Apparently [the same thing happens for Not An Answer flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229286/not-an-answer-isnt-blocked-after-flagging). It looks like there is no message at all coded into the dialog for those two flag reasons.

Comment: Interesting... I guess there's nothing else for me to do then. At least I know I'm not imagining things now. Thanks!

Comment: @animuson Since this apparently affects all of SE, should this be migrated to MSE? We could then link to it from the question you referred to.

Comment: No real point if it's already been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure enough, the low quality and not an answer flag types didn't present state when they were shown.  This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: I suspect this change [broke stuff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285317/you-have-already-raised-this-type-of-flag-no-i-havent).