# "you have already raised this type of flag" - no I haven't

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, not-an-answer

In [this late answer review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6942677) (and from the answer), I'm unable to flag this as not an answer.

[image]

It claims I have flagged it; I haven't...

Comment: Confirmed - I have apparently also raised that flag despite never seeing the post before.

Comment: Other than the weird message (which I saw too) the mod view of it looks entirely normal - no 'audits rewrote history' or strange clashing timestamps.

Comment: (Also just seen the same issue reported via flags on two futher answers)

Comment: Yes, it's not just this answer @Flexo; it's random other ones.

Comment: [Flag dialog tells me I've flagged a post I've never seen before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248080)

Comment: See comment [Flag dialog tells me I've flagged a post I've never seen before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/812678)

Comment: Just had the same on this question. Raised a custom flag instead.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995021/gui-update-in-qt/28322017#28322017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was in fact a regression.  It will be fixed very soon.  Details are here:  [Flag dialog tells me I've flagged a post I've never seen before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248080/flag-dialog-tells-me-ive-flagged-a-post-ive-never-seen-before)